# send post request from .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm new in Python and looking for some help :)

I created simple script which is checking IP reputation (from lists.txt) in IPVoid:

```
import requests
import re

URL = "https://www.ipvoid.com/ip-blacklist-check/"
ip = open('lists.txt')
DATA = {"ip":ip}

r = requests.post(url = URL, data = {"ip":ip})
text = r.text
bad_ones= re.findall(r'<i class="fa fa-minus-circle text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i> (.+?)</td>', text)

print(bad_ones)
```

The lists.txt contain list of IPs:

- 8.8.8.8
- 4.4.4.4

etc..

However, the script tooks only 1 line of the script - i would like to do "bulk" checking.

please advice :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether or not the ip addresses in the txt file are organized line by line, but I assume that this is the case.

You can do something like the following

```python
import requests
import re

URL = "https://www.ipvoid.com/ip-blacklist-check/"

bad_ones = []
with open('lists.txt') as f:
    for ip in f.readlines():
        r = requests.post(url = URL, data = {"ip":ip.strip()})
        text = r.text
        bad_ones.append(re.findall(r'<i class="fa fa-minus-circle text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i> (.+?)</td>', text))

print(bad_ones)
```

The `with open('lists.txt') as f` statement lets you
open the file and name the resulting io object as f, when the end of the 'with' block is  reached the file will be closed without explicitly calling `f.close()`.

Now for the batch mode it is a simple loop over each line of the text file, with a simple filter to get rid of the newline character by calling `strip()` on each `ip` string (the line of the text file).

Comment: that is what i was excepting :) now i know what to do, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not even sure if your above program works.. The `ip` variable in your program is basically a io object.

What you need is a for loop to send request for each and every IP.

You can do bulk checking if the API accepts them

```
import requests
import re

URL = "https://www.ipvoid.com/ip-blacklist-check/"
ips = open('lists.txt')

for ip in ips.readlines(): 
    DATA = {"ip":ip}

    r = requests.post(url = URL, data = {"ip":ip})
    text = r.text
    '''Your processing goes here..'''
```

Also explore using `with` clause for opening and closing files.